# Finding all directories with a certain string then changing permissions

Tags: permissions, find

I'm trying to combine two things.

I have to set permissions on a number of directories, all of which have "domain-" in their name.

I wanted to "find all directories in the current directory that have the string 'domain-' in their names and change the permissions to 755.

I keep getting syntax errors and am so frustrated that I just need to ask!

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the `find` command:

```
find . -type d -name 'domain-*' -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

- `.` specifies the path to search.
- `-type d` makes this only apply to directories.
- `-name ...` specifies the name of the directories this should apply to.
- `-exec ... {} +` is the command that will be run for each collection of matchs.

Comment: Thanks Thor, that was exactly what I needed and a nice explanation.